# Dynamic public path in webpack.config.js based on global variable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, global-variables

I have set a flag on the client-side using `window.value`. Now, I need to configure the `publicPath` in the webpack config based on this `window.value`. However, it seems that window is not defined inside webpack. Is there any other approach I can use to achieve this goal? I tried using `window.value` inside `webpack.config`, but it didn't work.